# How to make entries from an entry widget interact with each other

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to make a program which would allow a user to enter a currency and a US Dollar amount, and have the program run the conversion, and of course show the result to the user. I'm using tkinter and have a gui pop up where the user can enter in values, and as of now it just prints whatever the user entered on the IDLE window (to test whether what I have would do anything).

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
fields = 'Dollars' , 'Currency'
def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))


def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = []
    for field in fields:
        row = Frame(root)
        lab = Label(row, width = 15, text = field, anchor = 'w')
        ent = Entry(row)
        row.pack(side = TOP, fill = X, padx=5, pady = 5)
        lab.pack(side = LEFT)
        ent.pack(side = RIGHT, expand = YES, fill = X)
        entries.append((field, ent))
    return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e = ents: fetch(e)))
    b1 = Button(root, text = 'Show', command = (lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady =5)
    b2 = Button(root, text = 'Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    root.mainloop()
```

The only code that I have used for converting currency is something like this:

```
def convert():
    option = input("Please enter what you would like to convert $ to; Yen, Euros, or Pesos: ")
    dollars = eval(input("Please enter the dollar amount you wish to convert: "))
    if dollars < 0:
        print("You must enter a value greater than 0.")
        convert()
    elif option == "Yen":
        print("The amount of Yen you have is: ", dollars * 106.84)
    elif option == "Euros":
        print("The amount of Euros you have is: ", dollars * 0.77)
    elif option == "Pesos":
        print("The amount of Pesos you have is: ", dollars * 13.38)
```

I've looked across numerous websites, but I have not found any useful information anywhere on how to incorporate the two together. If anyone could help me understand what I need to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing the question: How to update the value of on Entry depending on the value of another Entry?
This seems to require code like:

```
value=eval(entryDollar.get())
entryCurrency.delete(0,END)
entryCurrency.insert(0,repr(value*exchangeRate))
```

In your current bindings with Show, `<Return>` it is unclear what direction you want to convert; a direction indicator might help.